# jQuery Browser Difference

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, browser

Since I have just started working in IT (internship started about 2 months ago) I will try to give you all the information you need to help me out.

I have a MVC4 Application that uses LongPolling to receive new data (in my case messages) from a server. Depending on the kind of the message, it will treat it differently on the client-side.

One kind of these messages are system messages:

I have two views. One view has a button, the other has just some text.
A click on the button then

> 1. sets some Properties in the controller and
> 2. forces a page reload on the other view, resulting in new content (e.g. some text boxes)

Now, if I have opened these two views in a new window,  it will work out just fine (in Firefox, IE and Chrome).
But if I have opened them in a new tab, it will only work in IE and Chrome. Firefox will receive the message, but it won't invoke the callback method.

```js
$(document).ready(function () { 
    ReadChat();
})
```

This initializes the first call to ReadChat().
As I mentioned earlier, it works perfectly fine in tabs in IE and Chrome, but only in new windows in Firefox.
If I check with FireBug, the response from the server arrives and I can look inside the JSON. It just doesn't invoke the callback for some reason.

My first thought being that not everything is loaded yet, I added a timeout to the first call.

If I write it like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function () { 
    setTimeout(ReadChat, 1000);
}
```

it also works in Firefox, as long as I do not set it lower than ~1000.

Has anyone come across the same problem? Why does Firefox make a difference here?

#### EDIT:

```js
function ReadChat() {
    $.fn.messaging({
        receiveURL: '@Url.Action("myAction", "myMethod")',
        myID: '@Model.myID',
        callback: function(data) {
            $.each(data.messages, function(k, v) {
                if(v.kind == 3) {
                    location.reload(true);
                }
            });
            ReadChat();
        }, timeout: 25000
    }, 'read');
}
```

Inside $.fn.messaging, the function for read will be called with the given parameters:

```
$.post(receiveURL, { id: myID }, function(response) {
    if($.isFunction(settings.callback) {
        settings.callback(response);
    }
}
```

#### EDIT2:

As Diesel337 said, I'm now using

```
$(this).ready(function () {
    ReadChat();
});
```

Opening in new tab:
Having made this adjustment, I tested it a bit more and at first glance it worked perfectly. Then i noticed, that if i click on the View, that should be reloaded, before clicking the button, it won't work. (The message is received, but the callback function not called)

On the other hand, if i ignored the View, that should be reloaded, and directly clicked the button, the page would reload without a problem.

It sounds really weird, i know, but if i don't look at the View, before clicking the button, it works.

I have also filed a new bug report on bugzilla about this.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it was not Firefox that was causing this problem but Firebug.
I tried to reproduce this error today once again and luckily had Firebug not active, so it worked like a charm.
After turning it on again to get any information on why this is, i got the same error.

Note: if you're developing something that requires an AJAX call on $(document).ready() better don't activate Firebug, because it will mess it up for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use $(this) instead of $(document) ?

```
$(this).ready(function() {
   ReadChat();
});
```

OR

```
$(function() {
   ReadChat();
});
```

Comment: After some more testing i realized it does work in tabs, EXCEPT when i click the tab, which does this AJAX call first. If i click the tab first, that sends the message, it works fine.